# Jquery very tasty Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have code which sets Cookie for every folder of domain (for example, domain.com and domain.com/folder, domain.com/folder2) have same Cookie name ("history") and different "history" values. How can i ignore Path for Cookie and add all Cookie value in same name ("history") even if Cookie was set from another folder? I used standart cookie.js (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and this additional code:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';path="/";' + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for ( var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkHistory(targetId) {
    var history = getCookie("history");
    var htmlContent = '';

    if (history != "") {
        var insert = true;
        var sp = history.toString().split(",");
        for ( var i = sp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            htmlContent += '<div id="recentViewes" data-recentViewes="'
                    + sp[i] + '"></div> ';
            if (sp[i] == document.URL) {
                insert = false;
            }
            document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = htmlContent;
        }
        if (insert) {
            sp.push(document.URL);
        }
        setCookie("history", sp.toString(), 30);
    } else {
        var stack = new Array();
        stack.push(document.URL);
        setCookie("history", stack.toString(), 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can. You can only access one cookie with a particular name, and it's always the one whose domain and folder are closest to the domain and folder of the page.

Comment: $.cookie('history', sp.toString(), { expires: 30, path: '/' }) (edit. > setCookie("history", sp.toString(), 30););  Can do this for me... But its work wrong with rest of code

Comment: @Barmar is correct. For posterity, 2 cookies with the same name are not recommended in the same path due to several problems, check here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/37#issuecomment-113964814

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by myself:

This code for page where you want to have History block:

```
function checkHistory(targetId) {
    var history = getCookie("history");
    var htmlContent = '';

    if (history != "") {
        var insert = true;
        var sp = history.toString().split(",");
        var se = decodeURIComponent(sp).split(",");
        for ( var i = se.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            htmlContent += '<div id="recentViewes" data-recentViewes="'
                    + se[i] + '"></div> ';
            if (se[i] == window.location.pathname) {
                insert = false;
            }
            document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = htmlContent;
        }
        if (insert) {
            se.push(window.location.pathname);
        }
        setCookie("history", se.toString(), 30);

    } else {
        var stack = new Array();
        stack.push(window.location.pathname);
        setCookie("history", stack.toString(), 30);
    }
}
```

And this for every folder/page of domain:

```
function checkHistory(targetId) {
    var history = getCookie("history");
    var htmlContent = '';

    if (history != "") {
        var insert = true;
        var sp = history.toString().split(",");     
        var se = decodeURIComponent(sp).split(",");

        for ( var i = se.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            htmlContent += '<div id="recentViewes" data-recentViewes="'
                    + se[i] + '"></div> ';
            if (se[i] == window.location.pathname) {
                insert = false;
            }
            document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = htmlContent;
        }
        if (insert) {
            se.push(window.location.pathname);
        }
 $.cookie('history', se.toString(), { expires: 30, path: '/' });

    } else {
        var stack = new Array();
        stack.push(window.location.pathname);
        $.cookie('history', stack.toString(), { expires: 30, path: '/' });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does one page use `getCookie` and `setCookie`, while the other uses `$.cookie`?